# boost timer same results in "for" loop?

Tags: c++, memory, boost, g++, alignment

I am testing my computer for speed regarding data alignment. The test is simple, process same buffer fetching data 2 bytes at a time, 4 bytes at a time and than 8 bytes. Processing the remaining (if present) few bytes with 2 bytes access. 
Test is described with details [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/).

My problem is when I do it in loop, I get exactly same printf results for time elapsed - what clearly cannot be true, and it is confirmed when I set breakpoint just at the beginning of loop - then new results seems to be correct. So I think this has to do something regarding compiler optimization (but I set -O0 flag for g++) but I don't know what exactly, I don't understand.

g++ 4.4.7 Ubuntu 12.10 NetBeans AMDx64

So what can I do?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int* itab=new int[1000*256]; //1MiB table  
    double elapsed=0;
    boost::timer* t=new boost::timer();
    Munge16(itab, 250);
    elapsed = t->elapsed();
    printf("Munge8 elapsed:%d\n", elapsed);
    t->restart();
    delete t;
    elapsed=0;
    delete itab;
}
```

result:

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

Munge8 elapsed:1721468076

---

with breakpoint here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
breakpoint >> int* itab=new int[1000*256]; //1MiB table
```

Munge8 elapsed:1721528944

Munge8 elapsed:1721529048

Munge8 elapsed:1721529174

Munge8 elapsed:1721529281

Munge8 elapsed:1721529496

Munge8 elapsed:1721529554

Munge8 elapsed:1721529643

Munge8 elapsed:1721529756

Munge8 elapsed:1721529808

Munge8 elapsed:1721529896

---

There is a solution, but I still don't get why boost::timer gives me such strange results.
The working solution is to use `gettimeofday` function from `<time.h>`.

```
class Timer {
private:

    timeval startTime;

public:

    void start(){
        gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
    }

    double stop(){
        timeval endTime;
        long seconds, useconds;
        double duration;

        gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);

        seconds  = endTime.tv_sec  - startTime.tv_sec;
        useconds = endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;

        duration = seconds + useconds/1000000.0;

        return duration;
    }

    long stop_useconds(){
        timeval endTime;
        long useconds;

        gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);
        useconds = endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;

        return useconds;
    }

    static void printTime(double duration){
        printf("%5.6f seconds\n", duration);
    }
};
```

test:

```
//test

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     void *vp = malloc(1024*sizeof(int));
     memset((int *)vp, 0, 1024);
    void* itab = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024*256); //1MiB table  
    if (itab) {
        memset ( (int*)itab, 0, 1024*256*sizeof (int) );
        float elapsed;

        boost::timer t;
        Timer timer = Timer();
        timer.start();

        Munge64(itab, 1024*256);

        double duration = timer.stop();
        long lt = timer.stop_useconds();
        timer.printTime(duration);
        cout << t.elapsed() << endl;
        elapsed = t.elapsed();
        cout << ios::fixed << setprecision(10) << elapsed << endl;
        cout << ios::fixed << setprecision(10) << t.elapsed() << endl;
        printf("Munge8 elapsed:%ld useconds\n", lt);

        elapsed = 0;
        free(vp);
        free(itab);
        //printf("Munge8 elapsed:%d\n", elapsed);
    }
}
```

results:

0.000100 seconds

0 << ??????????

40 << ????????????????

40 << ???????????????????????????????????

Munge8 elapsed:100 useconds

0.000100 seconds

0

40

40

Munge8 elapsed:100 useconds

0.000099 seconds

0

40

40

Munge8 elapsed:99 useconds

Comment: Perhaps you should make sure that what you're asking `printf` to print is what you're actually passing it.  `%d` isn't expecting a double.

Comment: yes, but this is not the reason why every result is the same

Comment: It actually could be.  A `double` is 8 bytes, `%d` takes 4 of those bytes and uses them as if they were an integer.  The bit representation of part of the double could be the same for different values since you're only seeing half of it.  As you've discovered it's possible your timer is not giving you the information you wanted, but even if it had, your output would not have been even close to what you might expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use boost::timer - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/timer/doc/original_timer.html#Class timer

On POSIX like it measures CPU time - not wall clock time.

Consider using boost::chrono or std::chrono - you would want to look at steady_clock - as other clocks when implementing a timer if you want to isolate yourself from drift or shift in system wall clock.